# Can't import cx_Oracle in docker image

Tags: python, oracle, docker, cx-oracle

I'm building a python file with docker. In this python file, I `import cx_Oracle` to do something with oracle. I can run the python file successfully via ternimal:

`[root@master files]# python3 myfile.py`

Then I build a docker image based on this file. Here is the content of the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONPATH /root/files
WORKDIR ./
COPY myfile.py ./
CMD [ "python3", "myfile.py" ]
```

Then build the image:
`[root@master files]# docker build -f Dockerfile -t test:1.0 .`

The building was successful. However, when I trying to run the image through `docker run --name test test:1.0` it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TimedTransfer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Transfer import TransferTPI
  File "/Transfer.py", line 7, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'
```

Could someone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: It means there is no 'cx_Oracle' module in the base image. You can find another base image include the module or install the module in the Dockerfiel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a line in the Dockerfile and then the Dockerfile will like this:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONPATH /root/files

# install the 'cx_Oracle' module
RUN apt-get -y update && python3 -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade

WORKDIR ./
COPY myfile.py ./
CMD [ "python3", "myfile.py" ]
```

Then the image will contain the 'cx_Oracle' module.